# How does the 6502 handle effective address overflow in indexed addressing modes?

Tags: emulation, microprocessors, 6502

What happens if the result of the addition performed in indexed addressing modes is greater than `0xFFFF`? To be clear, I am referring not to the carry from the lower to the higher byte, but rather to the carry from the higher byte.

For example, for an instruction using absolute X-indexed addressing, what would be the result of calling it with an operand of `0xFFAA` when the x-index register contains `0xFF`? Would this overflow into `0x00AA`? Would the result of `0x100A9` be truncated to `0x00A9`? Would the processor freeze?

For some reason there is no information on this anywhere. This does not even seem to be mentioned in MOS' official programming guide for the 650X family.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The processor will not freeze.

It wraps around. Exactly how it wraps around depends on the addressing mode, as pointed out by @JeremyP.

#### The normal 16-bit addressing mode

After `0xFFFF` it wraps around to `0x0000`.

`0xFFAA` + `0x00FF` will map to `0x00A9`

#### The explicit zero-page addressing mode

If you are using the special zero-page addressing mode, i.e. which can only hold an 8-bit address, it wraps around *within* zero-page only, from `0xFF` to `0x00`.

`0xAA` + `0xFF` will map to `0xA9`, i.e. to the 16-bit address `0x00A9`.

Comment: Thanks, @Eureka! Do you have a source for that, please?

Comment: Not that I can find. This is standard behaviour of microprocessors. If their address space is N bits long, and you go beyond that, they just wrap round to the start (i.e. ignore the carry into the N+1th bit), without giving an error.

Comment: Would that also set the carry flag? Or is the carry flag only reserved for arithmetic performed as part of the actual instruction?

Comment: I would not expect it to set the carry flag.

Comment: @Vadim You do have to be careful of zero page addressing e.g. `lda $aa,x` This only wraps around within the zero page. So if x contains `$ff` the above gives you an effective address of `$a9` not `$1a9`